# Unable to connect to localhost server with Azeroth core

Tags: connection, localhost, azerothcore

I'm having issues connecting to a localhost server using Azeroth Core. The server is up and running, I've set the realmlist ip as 127.0.0.1, both in the MSQL and in my client, yet it doesn't seem like I can connect to it. Any help would be appreciated.
[Screenshot of client and server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLEJr.png)

Comment: what does your realmlist.wtf look like? should have something like `set realmlist 127.0.0.1`

Comment: have you tried deleting the `WTF` directory of your client? then check again the realmlist and try again

Comment: Hello, I've tried deleting the WTF directory, it did not help. I already had the realmlist in the path, "data/enUS/realmlist.wtf" set to "set realmlist 127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

> Authserver listening to `0.0.0.0:8085`

You changed the default port of the `authserver` process to `8085`. That's supposed to be the port of the `worldserver` instead.

The client uses by default the port `3724` so that should be the port you should set as [RealmServerPort](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/authserver/authserver.conf.dist#L53) of your `authserver.conf` configuration file.

```
RealmServerPort = 3724
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm now stuck on "logging in to gameserver" with the realmlist briefly closing when I select AzerothCore, and then opens again a few seconds later.

Comment: @KlavsIndiusBækgaard that's another issue then ;)